# What free gis is on android that leads in the area? -- just name top 1-2

Tags: android

similar kind of q of to [What are some Free and Open Source GIS Desktop packages](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24/what-are-some-free-and-open-source-gis-desktop-packages)

include evidence such as 4.8-5 rating out of 5, etc.

Comment: Please include *justifications* in the replies, not just lists of apps.

Comment: this mod is ace =)

Comment: isnt it sth List of Gis Applications for Android tablets[here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/12452/list-of-gis-applications-for-android-tablets)

Answer (score 1):

qgis, because it has universal availability meaning that there is great portability of projects between android and other OS.

Answer (score 1):

We develop a mobile GIS solution for Android tablets named **Mappt**.  Mappt allows you to import, edit and export GIS data via KML or Shapefile, and is fully functional offline.

Details can be found in another post I made, here:

https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/80580/21955